# Replacing a certain number of characters after a match in regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to find any instance of

`\/Network\/Cambric Corporate Center\/`

and replace the next 8 characters with nothing. 
So something like this

`\/Network\/Cambric Corporate Center\/1164.DEV1164`

Turns into this

`\/Network\/Cambric Corporate Center\/1164`

I'm working with a baked in replace regular expression visual programming piece, and this is my first post to here ever so please ask if more info is needed. I basically just need it to look like this

`\/Network\/Cambric Corporate Center\/1164`

if there is another solution without having to use replace
It is for a frequently updated mass source of data that I need to edit to make more compatible with arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `(\/Network\/Cambric Corporate Center\/).{8}` and replace with $1 to keep the first group but not anything else.

Here's the regex with the replacement: https://regex101.com/r/F4Y4VD/1

Comment: Sorry I actually had a typo in the OP

`\/Network\/Cambric Corporate Center\/1164.DEV`

Edited to 

`\/Network\/Cambric Corporate Center\/1164`

Comment: I fixed my answer, I had `\.` instead of `.`